# How to disable this payment method in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I validate my basket in woocommerce, I am redirected to the page 'Confirmation of the order', then there is this payment method that I want to deactivate
[image]

how to deactivate it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the payment methods by going **WooCommerce -> Settings -> Payments**  there you can enable/disable any payment method.